# Using a variable to direct traffic

Tags: php, authentication

I am mostly sure that my error is with the variable not being gotten from the table.  However I can not see the error I am asking for that data at the same time I am asking for the username and password.  The table consists of [username],[password],[company].  The goal is to have the user get directed based on the name in company after the username and password have been verified.  I keep getting the echo at the end.

Here is the code

```
   function RegisterUser($usename, $password, $company)
{
   // hash the pwd
   $hpwd = hash('sha256',$password);
   $q ='insert into users values(username, password, company) values(?,?,?)';
   $stmt = PDO::prepare($q);
   $stmt->exectue(array( $username, $hpwd, $company));
}
// validate user and return the company if successfull

function ValidateUser($username, $password, &$company)
{
   $hpwd = hash('sha256',$password);
   $q ='select company from users where username=? AND password=?';
   $stmt = PDO::prepare($q);
   $stmt->exectue(array( $username, $hpwd));
   if( ($company = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) === false )
   {
     $company = header( 'Location: login.php' );
   } 

   elseif($company == "monkeynones"){
        header( 'Location: admin1.php' );
        }
```

Comment: You are mostly sure? Just dump the content in `$row` and check if it's empty. I would make it much clearer. Also, as far as I know, you don't need to have `password`, `company` and `username` in quotes like that. I think you mean to use `\``, altough I might be wrong.

Comment: [mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: I added those to indicate the column name and just do a print_r on $row?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'password' and 'company' from users where 'username' = '$username';";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT `password`, `company` from `users` where `username` = '$username'";
```

Use backticks, not quotes, around identifiers. `and` is replaced by a comma, and the trailing semicolon in the query isn't required.

Comment: I tried it and I get the same response it prints the echo at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

It is so important that new programmers learn to do username/password authentication properly I felt it necessary to write this longer post.

Firstly, as eicto pointed out, the mysql extension is both deprecated and should really not even be used ever.

So to the metal.
visit php.net and learn about [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo)

Never store unencoded passwords.

here is what you should do:

set up PDO:

```
// you need to store $link somewhere. in a class preferrably
function InitPDO(&$link)
{
   // havet the database handle all strings as UTF-8.
   $options = array('PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND' => 'set names utf8');
   $link = new PDO ( 'mysql:host='.$config['dsn_host'].';dbname='.$config['dsn_db'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $options ) ;

   // If there is an error executing database queries, have PDO to throw an exception.
   $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
```

upon registration of user.

```
function RegisterUser($username, $password, $company)
{
   // hash the pwd
   $hpwd = hash('sha256',$password);
   $q ='insert into users values(username, password, company) values(?,?,?)';
   $stmt = $link->prepare($q);
   $stmt->execute(array( $username, $hpwd, $company));
}
```

// validate user and return the company if successfull

```
function ValidateUser($username, $password, &$company)
{
   $hpwd = hash('sha256',$password);
   $q ='select company from users where username=? AND password=?';
   $stmt = $link->prepare($q);
   $stmt->execute(array( $username, $hpwd));
   if( ($company = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)) === false )
   {
     $company = 'invalid'; // because user auth failed';
   } 
   //else all is good
}
```

example test usage.

```
// assumes there is a 'login.php' and a 'invalid.php' file
$link = null;
InitPDO( $link );
RegisterUser('tester','password','login');
VerifyUser('tester','password', $redir );
if( file_exists( $redir . '.php' ) )
{
   header( 'Location: '. $redir . '.php' );
   exit;
}
echo 'error. no valid page found to fullfill query';
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' for the 4th line of code.  I agree that this is important and that is why I am trying to make sure that I understand it.  It has been mentioned to me about the deprecated code I will make sure that I start to learn the changes.  Thanks for your help.  I have been struggling with this for a week ad a half before I turned to the community.

Comment: I added the ; at the end of the line and that cleared that and I added the extra perens.  Now it seems to be working because I get a blank page.  Any advice on how to use the company to move them along and can I keep the company to then determine content when they get to the user page?

Comment: I took a stab in the dark and surmised you'd infer that the 'invalid company ...' text would be the name of your default 'invalid user' page.  as far as additional meta data relating to other content based on company.. I'd suggest adding more db fields. return them and use them as you see fit.

Comment: I added what modifications I made in the original post.  I edited the post.  I am just getting a blank page with the address of the validation code.

Comment: well..your question is no longer really valid or true by virtue of changing your code to what I supplied you.  none the less.. i've edited it further to explain how to use the functions I described.